# Elements not adding to JList

Tags: swing, jlist

For some reason, I can't add anything to my JList. The JList is visible but simply shows white - nothing can be selected.

```
List list;
DefaultListModel listModel;
//...
list = new JList();
list.setBounds(220,20,150,200);
listModel = new DefaultListModel();
listModel.addElement("ONE");
panel.add(list);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JList` is not using the `listModel`.

One way is to initialize the `JList` by specifying a `ListModel` to use:

```
DefaultListModel listModel = ...
JList list = new JList(listModel);
```

Then, performing changes to the `listModel` (such as calling `addElement`) will cause the changes to appear on the `JList`.

For more information on using `JList`s, the [How to Use Lists](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) lesson from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) is a good source.

Answer (score 0):

You never set the list's model to the ListModel you've constructed.